# Clojure hashing algorithm

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have working code where I get hash code of data structures with `(hash data-structure)` but it works in small amount of them. When I have few millions of data structures it will start giving me duplicate hashes (clash). How to get something more unique when structure of data structure is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always resort to md5 (or anything else, really).

```
(defn md5 [^String s]
    (let [algorithm (MessageDigest/getInstance "MD5")
          raw (.digest algorithm (.getBytes s))]
        (format "%032x" (BigInteger. 1 raw))))

(defn md5-hash [s] (md5 (pr-str s)))

(md5-hash {:a [1 2 3 '(5 6 7)]})

=> "8f941424e629b876cdcb51509521870d"
```

also, you can use Java serialization instead of `pr-str`.

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/weavejester/whorl) has existed for a while, and I've seen at least one alternative.